# How to fix data anomalies in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

To gain read performance, data model in Cassandra are denormalized to certain extend.

As denormalized produces duplicated record, how to avoid data anomalies?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there could be 2 ways to keep your data in different column family(CF) consistent:

1. Whenever you update row/column value in one CF, also update the
   corresponding row/column in other CF.
2. Run some background batch
   process to reconcile column values to make them consistent.

Which way you want to use, that may depends on how you did you model your data, and how strict is your application's requirement for data consistency among different CF.

Comment: Do you have any example on this?

Comment: yes, jbellis's answer "atomic batch" gave more specific details that can be used to make data consistent in different CFs. This should be used in both synchronous update (1) and cron job to reconcile data (2).

Answer (score 1):

jsfeng's answer is good on general principles, but a more specific answer is to use atomic batches:  www.datastax.com/dev/blog/atomic-batches-in-cassandra-1-2